# give unique generated values to simple storage

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, local-storage, storage

i want to store my data in firefox addon `localstorage` is not working in firefox addon so tried simple-storage i want give names for `simple storage` like we assigning to `localstorage` like this

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
localStorage[i] = data[i];
}
```

when i tried simple-storage `ss.storage.i` it won't work.
is that possible to store data like this or is there anyother alternate ways to store like this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

converting the comment from above to the answer. the issues is you have to use brackets. i dont know much about ss.stroage though btw.

`ss.storage[i]`